# Open prettyPhoto gallery using onclick?

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I am trying to open prettyPhoto from click event. 
All goes perfect when it is one image, but I need to open a gallery. Pleassee help!

Thanks in advance and sorry my bad english!!

This is the code

**HTML:**

```
<a href="http://domain.com/bigimage.jpg" onclick="return fancybox(this);><img scr="http://domain.com/smallimage.jpg" /></a>
```

**JSCode:**

```
function fancybox(elem) {
    elem = jQuery(elem);
    //elem = jQuery('#gallery_one img').attr('src');

    if (!elem.data("fancybox")) {
        elem.data("fancybox", true);
        elem.prettyPhoto({
             opacity:0.80,
             default_width:500,
             default_height:344,
             theme:'light_square'
        });
        elem.prettyPhoto().trigger('click');
        alert(elem);
    }
return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function fancyboxmanual(elem) {
        jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
        elem = jQuery(elem);

        var gallery = "#" +elem.data("gallery");
        jQuery(gallery).find(".fancybox").eq(0).click();
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="marker point galeria" id="plaza-italia">

        <a class="manualfancybox" onclick='return fancyboxmanual(this);' data-gallery="gallery_italia" href="#nogo"> 
            <img src="mapa/referent-points/plaza-italia.jpg" width="100%"/>
        </a>

        <div id="gallery_italia" style="display:none">
            <a rel="prettyPhoto[galleryitalia]" class="fancybox" href="mapa/referent-points/plaza-italia.jpg" title="Plaza Italia">
                <img src="mapa/referent-points/plaza-italia.jpg" alt=""/>
            </a>
            <a rel="prettyPhoto[galleryitalia]" class="fancybox" href="mapa/referent-points/plaza-italia-2.jpg" title="Plaza Italia">
                <img src="mapa/referent-points/plaza-italia-2.jpg" alt=""/>
            </a>
            <a rel="prettyPhoto[galleryitalia]" class="fancybox" href="mapa/referent-points/plaza-italia-3.jpg" title="Plaza Italia">
                <img src="mapa/referent-points/plaza-italia-3.jpg" alt=""/>
            </a>
        </div>
</div>
```